# java replacing back strokes with other characters

Tags: java, string

I have come across this little problem.

```
    String fileAdress = "c:\red\";
    System.out.println("Peach " + fileAdress);
    fileAdress = fileAdress.replaceAll("\", "\\\\");
    System.out.println("Steel " + fileAdress);
```

or

```
    String fileAdress = "c:\\red\\";
    System.out.println("Peach " + fileAdress);
    fileAdress = fileAdress.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
    System.out.println("Steel " + fileAdress);
```

I would like to convert the fileAddress to be to the following

```
    String fileAdress = "c:\\\\red\\\\";
```

Would it be possible to advise of where I am making the error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead of [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) - `replaceAll` takes a regular expression as the first argument, which isn't what you want. This should be fine:

```
fileAddress = fileAddress.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

(I wish `replaceAll` had been called `regexReplace` or something more obvious - this problem comes up a lot.)